# Hartl Ruby-on-Rails Tutorial (3.2), Section 8.2.6 - Sign out link not returning anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting the following error after completing the sign out part of the tutorial:

```
Failures:

1) User pages signup with valid information after saving the user 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_link('Sign out') }
   expected link "Sign out" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:49:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.15 seconds
48 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:49 # User pages signup with valid information after saving the user
```

I had more errors before, but I ended up rearranging the order of items in the authentication_pages_spec.rb. Is the order of items that important? What am I missing with this error?

**authentication_pages_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

subject { page }

describe "signin page" do
before { visit signin_path }

it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign in') }
it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
end

describe "signin" do
before { visit signin_path }

describe "with invalid information" do
  before { click_button "Sign in" }

  it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
  it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid') }

  describe "after visiting another page" do
    before { click_link "Home" }
    it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
end
end

describe "with valid information" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before do
    fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: user.password
    click_button "Sign in"
  end

  describe "followed by signout" do
    before { click_link "Sign out" }
    it { should have_link('Sign in') }
  end

  it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
  it { should have_link('Profile', href: user_path(user)) }
  it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
  it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }
end
end
end
```

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def new
end

def create
user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
  sign_in user
  redirect_to user
else
  flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
  render 'new'
end
end

def destroy
sign_out
redirect_to root_path
end
end
```

**sessions_helper.rb**

```
module SessionsHelper

def sign_in(user)
cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
current_user = user
end

def current_user=(user)
@current_user = user
end

def current_user
@current_user ||= user_from_remember_token
end



private

def user_from_remember_token
  remember_token = cookies[:remember_token]
  User.find_by_remember_token(remember_token) unless remember_token.nil?
end


def signed_in?
!current_user.nil?
end

def sign_out
current_user = nil
cookies.delete(:remember_token)
end

end
```

**user_pages_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

subject { page }

describe "signup page" do
before { visit signup_path }

it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign up') }
it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up')) }
end

describe "profile page" do
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
before { visit user_path(user) }

it { should have_selector('h1',    text: user.name) }
it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
end

describe "signup" do

before { visit signup_path }

let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

describe "with invalid information" do
  it "should not create a user" do
    expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
  end
end

describe "with valid information" do
  before do
    fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
    fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
    fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
    fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
  end



  it "should create a user" do
    expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
  end

  describe "after saving the user" do
    it { should have_link('Sign out') }
    end
  end
end

end
```

Comment: The error you get is in `/spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb` but you just show the `authentication_pages_spec.rb`. Maybe you're looking for the solution in the wrong place.

Comment: I just added the user_pages_spec.rb.....any thoughts?

Comment: See my answer below, the problem (I think) it's in the test flow, the submit button is not clicked when you enter the "after saving the user" branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operations done in the "should create a user" test are not done before the "after saving the user" test just because are after it (ugly explaination).

The submit button is not clicked when you enter the "after saving the user" test branch, you could fix this by clicking the submit button again (see below).

Try to use something like this, it should work but I don't know if there is a better way to write this test (avoiding this tiny duplication):

```
# user_pages_spec.rb
# ...
describe "with valid information" do
  before do
    fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
    fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
    fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
    fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
  end

  it "should create a user" do
    expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
  end

  describe "after saving the user" do
    before { click_button submit }
    it { should have_link('Sign out') }
  end
end
```

Comment: By having two "click_button"s aren't you creating two identical users?  Won't which ever test runs second  always fail?

Comment: Hi @tir38 nope because they are two separate specs and the DB is cleaned.